# How to serialize any RDF data

Tags: javascript, rdf, ontology, solid

I'm fetching various ontologies from the web and they come in a broad variety of formats. I'd like to use rdflib.js to serialize them to jsonld. The `.serialize(target, kb, base, contentType, callback, options)` method of rdflib takes several arguments that are not documented and I could not guess them from reading the source at https://linkeddata.github.io/rdflib.js/doc/serialize.js.html

```js
const ont = await fetch('http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/');
const jsonlddata = rdflib.serialize(ont, ...?);
```

Comment: do you want to know how to do it using rdflib.js or do you only want the serialize the ontologies in jsonld ?

Comment: shouldn't you load the file into a graph `g=rdflib.Graph()` with `g.load('http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/')` . And then just something like  `g.serialize("PATH_TO_FILE", format='json-ld', indent=4)`?

Comment: @Noor I'd like to know the most simple way. Performance is secondary in my use case.

Comment: @AKSW I most likely should do that. If this works, you should post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it (=

Comment: Funnily enough, a [github issue on the `rdflib.js` project](https://github.com/linkeddata/rdflib.js/issues) is likely to get answers about "arguments that are not documented" and other advice from the developers themselves...